# List users with the most posts in the last 30 days

Tags: mysql, wpdb, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to create a MySQL query to display a descending list of users with the most number of posts over the last 30 days.

This is not working with me:

```
$where .= " AND post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-30 days')) . "'";
$top_users = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT COUNT(ID) AS post_count, post_author, post_date, user_id FROM $wpdb->posts, $wpdb->usermeta WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_author = $wpdb->usermeta.user_id AND post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish' $where");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you need.

```
<?php
    $date = new DateTime('NOW');
    $date->sub(new DateInterval('P30D'));  //30 Days Interval
    echo $back30days= $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";

    global $wpdp;
    $top_users = $wpdb->get_results("select count(users.user_nicename) as posts, users.user_nicename as user_name from $wpdb->users as users join $wpdb->posts as posts where users.ID = posts.post_author AND posts.post_status='publish' AND posts.post_date_gmt > '$back30days' GROUP BY users.user_nicename ORDER BY count(users.user_nicename) DESC"); 

    echo '<h3>In Past 30 Days</h3>';
    foreach ($top_users as $top_user){
        echo '<p>'.$top_user->user_name.' has written '.$top_user->posts.' posts</p>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks! The code works except for the date part; I get an error;
`Fatal error: Call to undefined method DateTime::sub()`.
Instead, I used this code for date query:
`$today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$monthago = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime(date('Y-m-j H:i:s')) - (7 * 24 * 60 * 60));`

`posts.post_date BETWEEN '$monthago' AND '$today'`